# zsh prompt in read/echo for variable input

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh, echo, prompt

I want to make a script for zsh command line. It is a separate .sh file, I launch it through bash myscriptname, it asks me to input some values for variables and provides a result.
The problem is the following. If I use prompt though echo it works fine. But if I put prompt into straight into read (I want the input to be on the same line) I get a different outcome. Upon launch, it prints a space line and for any next input (enter or any other key) gives me "not a valid input".

script 1 (prompt in echo)

```
echo "type in v1 "
read v1
echo "Variable v1 is equal to $v1"
```

script 2 (prompt in read)

```
read "?type in v1 " v1
echo "Variable v1 is equal to $v1"
```

How should this be fixed?

Comment: So you want to execute a bash program from a zsh command line? This is perfectly fine: From a zsh command line you can execute programs in any programming language, be it bash, sh, Perl, COBOL or whatever. Invoking `bash myscriptname` is also one valid way to do it. However, the tagging of your question confuses me: There is nothing zsh related in your question. You run a bash script, and this means that we are talking about bash code here. May I suggest that you replace the _zsh_ tag by a _bash_ tag?